# Call C standard library function from asm in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, linker-errors, masm

I have a problem with calling C function from asm project created in visual studio (Win10 x64, Visual Studio 2015). Project consist of one asm file:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none
includelib msvcrt.lib

ExitProcess PROTO return:DWORD
extern printf:near

.data
text BYTE "Text", 0

.code
main PROC
    push offset text
    call printf
    add esp,4
    invoke ExitProcess,0
main ENDP
end main
```

When I build project, linker outputs the error:

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in
>   function _main@0

Linker output parameters:

> /OUT:"C:\Users\apple\Documents\SP_Lab7\Debug\SP_Lab7_Demo.exe"
>   /MANIFEST:NO /NXCOMPAT
>   /PDB:"C:\Users\apple\Documents\SP_Lab7\Debug\SP_Lab7_Demo.pdb"
>   /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib"
>   "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib"
>   "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /MACHINE:X86 /SAFESEH:NO
>   /INCREMENTAL:NO
>   /PGD:"C:\Users\apple\Documents\SP_Lab7\Debug\SP_Lab7_Demo.pgd"
>   /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'"
>   /ManifestFile:"Debug\SP_Lab7_Demo.exe.intermediate.manifest"
>   /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

If I comment `call print`, then everything executes normally (even Windows API function). Is there any way to call C function from asm file without creating cpp file that includes `<cstdio>`? 
Is it possible to do?

Comment: A work around is to set the `platform toolset` to VS 2013. To do that pull down the `Project` menu select `properties...` . Go to `Configuration Properties`/`General`, and change `Platform Toolset` to **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)**

Comment: @MichaelPetch It's really working, thank you

Comment: Microsoft refactored much of the C runtime. Some functions are no longer exported in the library (some are defined in a _C_ header file). MS has some compatibility libraries _legacy_stdio_definitions.lib_ and _legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib_ , but I have yet to get printf to work with them, so I fall back to _VS 2013 toolset_. There may be another work around for it, but I haven't seen it.

Comment: I have added a new answer with a solution you might be interested in trying. It uses the Visual Studio 2015 toolset. You will have to switch from Visual Studio 2013 toolset to 2015 before trying it. I am very cruious if this works for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft refactored much of the *C* runtime and libraries in VS 2015. Some functions are no longer exported from the *C* library (some are defined in a *C* header file). Microsoft has some compatibility libraries like *legacy_stdio_definitions.lib* and *legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib*, but you can also choose to use the older Visual Studio 2013 platform toolset with the older *C* libraries.

To change the platform toolset: pull down the `Project` menu; select `Properties...`; go to `Configuration Properties`/`General`, and change `Platform Toolset` to **Visual Studio 2013 (v120)**

Answer (score 10):

It appears that it' possible to use the Visual Studio 2015 Toolset with a few modifications.

- You'll need to add these libraries to your dependencies: *libcmt.lib*, *libvcruntime.lib*, *libucrt.lib*, *legacy_stdio_definitions.lib*. Alternatively you could use `includelib` to include these libraries in your assembly file.
- Specify *C* calling convention for your `main` procedure using `PROC C`
- At the end of your file (and this is important) do not use `end main`, use `end` only. Not fixing this may cause unexpected crashes.
- Although we can use *ExitProcess* to exit our application, we can also put the return code in *EAX* and do a `ret` to return. The *C* runtime calls our `main` function, and will call the shutdown code for us upon returning.

The code could look like:

```
.586
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap:none

includelib libcmt.lib
includelib libvcruntime.lib
includelib libucrt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

ExitProcess PROTO return:DWORD
extern printf:NEAR

.data
text BYTE "Text", 0

.code
main PROC C                    ; Specify "C" calling convention
    push offset text
    call printf
    add  esp, 4
;   invoke ExitProcess,0       ; Since the C library called main (this function)
                               ; we can set eax to 0 and use ret`to have
                               ; the C runtime close down and return our error
                               ; code instead of invoking ExitProcess
    mov eax, 0
    ret
main ENDP
end                            ; Use `end` on a line by itself
                               ; We don't want to use `end main` as that would
                               ; make this function our program entry point
                               ; effectively skipping by the C runtime initialization
```

Comment: It seems that just `includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` is sufficient in visual studio 2022. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/overview-of-potential-upgrade-issues-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170#errors-involving-crt-functions

Answer (score 1):

You can call C functions, but then you'll need to link with the C library. Exactly how that is done will depend on what C library you want to link with. I'd suggest finding a minimal C runtime, such as the [WCRT library](http://wcrt.sourceforge.net/).

The library will probably require initialization, and might require you to define a bunch of buffers somewhere for its book keeping.

Instead of going to all this trouble, I'd suggest you just stick to Windows API, and in your case use the [WriteConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

Comment: thanks for pointing to use WinAPI functions, because the main function that I wanted was `strcspn` and similar function `StrSpn` is available. But I still don't understand, why `includelib msvcrt.lib` don't load C library.