# Platform Toolset change on VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I need to do some Assembly coding on VS 2015 and for it I need to use an include file that uses certain C functions. The file worked perfectly on VS 2012 and 2013, but due to some library changes on VS 2015 (as far as I understand), it gives an error on the linking process. So, I was advised to set my Platform Toolset back to VS 2012 or lower, but the only ones that appear on the changing menu are the 2015 ones. I tried to download and install the said toolkits, but even then they don't appear in the drop-out menu. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or is there another way to do this? (eg. an include file with basic print and _getch functions that works on VS 2015) Here is a screenshot of the Toolset selection screen, if it helps:

[image: Toolset selection screen]

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721059/call-c-standard-library-function-from-asm-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I did check that question before, that was where I got the idea of using a previous Toolset. I also tried to include the libraries manually like is also suggested, but with no success (I am still a begginer).