# Unable to change Platform Toolset Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have a C# solution in Visual Studio 2015 with two projects, the applications run perfectly on Win 7 and up however, they will not run on XP. I've done the mandatory research and seen that I need to update my Platform Toolset setting and include a few dlls, however, when trying to follow the steps (as listed on this site and MS's) I do not see the options for configuring this.

An similar question on this site showed a screenshot with an example but when I try to navigate to the configuration options for this project (not solution) I do not see the "Platform Toolset" setting, much less anything else shown on the example.

Firstly, viewing the property pages of one of the projects shows an entirely different UI with no "Configuration Properties" and the only way for me to view a form similar to the example is to view the properties of the entire solution (against [MS instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx))

[**Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35663572/platform-toolset-change-on-vs-2015)
[image: Example Platform Toolset setting]

**My Project Property Page**
[image]

**My Solution Properties**
[image]

As you would see, the dialog does not offer a "General" tab and neither of the projects within the solution have the ability to view the configurations.

I've inherited this application and am not sure what was done during the creation of the solution and projects that may have caused this. Any ideas? Is there something that was done incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is from a `C++` project, whereas your project is a `C#` project, hence why the two look completely different.

Windows XP does not support .NET 4.5, so you will have to downgrade to an earlier version of .NET ([Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/dotnet45xp/)).

The drop-down to do this is clearly displayed in your "My Project Property Page" screenshot (labelled as "Target Framework"). The latest supported version for XP is .NET 4.

It is worth noting that Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft (unless you are paying for extended support - and even that runs out in a year or so). It is not recommended that it is used.

Comment: I clearly had no idea it was that simple, thank you @RB there's no choice with the target OS as it's a server running Win 2003.

Comment: @Daniel Also unsupported, but I've worked in enterprises long enough to know why you can't change that ;-)