# Program written for MASM won't run: unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in function _main

Tags: assembly, visual-studio-2015, masm

I can't get an assembly language program used as an example in the book [**Guide to Assembly Language: A Concise Introduction by James T. Streib**](http://www.jtstreib.com/GuideAssemblyLanguage.html) to run. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm following these instructions: http://www.jtstreib.com/VStudio13.html I've gone through all the steps as described in that guide, but the program still won't run. Trying to assemble it, I get this error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _printf referenced in function _main
LNK1120 1 unresolved externals
```

The source code:

```
.386
.model flat, c
.stack 100h

printf proto arg:ptr byte

.data
    msg byte "Hello World!", 0Ah, 00h

.code
main proc
    invoke printf, addr msg
    ret
main endp
end
```

Comment: This question may be related to SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721059/call-c-standard-library-function-from-asm-in-visual-studio (It might even be a duplicate). I provided a couple of answers to resolve the other question that may apply here.

Comment: I don't see `Visual Studio 2013 (v120)` or anything like that listed in `Platform Toolset`. The only thing I got is `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)` and `Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)`

Comment: Just curious, do you happen to be using VS 2015 Express edition?

Comment: Yes. Community Edition. By the way, the second answer is not working for me either. I get a bunch of errors like this: `LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'libcmt.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`

Comment: I tweaked something and now it compiles, but crashes.

Comment: Yep, it does. I just checked.

Comment: I have no idea what mode I'm using.

Comment: Where exactly do I need to add this /NODEFAULTLIB:library ? Though, that's just a warning.

Comment: The file compiles as a 32-bit application fine save only for a bunch of warnings, but crashes on me every time I try to run it. As a 64-bit application, it doesn't compile. The assembler throws all sorts of errors at me.

Comment: It also appears that if you Install (Everything) the installer has an option for "Windows 8.1 And Windows Phone 8/8.1" which has the option to install the "Tools and Windows SDK". I believe that includes the VS2013 toolset.

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I've been tweaking things here and there and now everything seems to work just fine (with those four include library lines included, of course).

Comment: Glad you got it going! Had to be something in the environment or project interfering (that you fixed). Very hard to know. In a normal environment it should just work.