# How to link Windows universal CRT to obj file compiled with nasm

Tags: linker, nasm, crt, universal-crt

Environment:  Windows 10.  I happen to be using a MinGW version of `ld` for linking, but I'm happy to use the visual studio `link.exe` if it makes things simpler.

I have the following basic program in nasm:

```
    global  _main
    extern  _printf

    section .text
_main:
    push    message
    call    _printf
    add     esp, 4
    ret
message:
    db  'Hello, World', 10, 0
```

And it builds fine using

```
nasm -f win32 test.nasm
```

When trying to link it to the windows CRT (ucrt.lib), I get the following error:

```
$ ld -o test.exe test.obj
test.obj:test.nasm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `printf'
```

Ok, so I need to point the linker at the ucrt library:

```
$ ld -o test.exe /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Windows\ 
Kits/10/Lib/10.0.14393.0/ucrt/x86/ucrt.lib test.obj
test.obj:test.nasm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `printf'
```

Trying the equivalent with the visual studio linker:

```
d:\Code\nasm>link -out:test.exe -entry:main -subsystem:console test.obj
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.10.25017.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

This raises a couple of questions:

1. Why does one of these try to find `printf` and the other, `_printf`?  I get that there's an underscore convention, but it doesn't seem to be understood by both linkers.
2. I used `objdump -t` to look at the symbols in the ucrt.lib file.  I won't paste the entire list, but it contains entries such as:

`[  4](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __imp____conio_common_vcprintf`

`[  5](sec  3)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 ___conio_common_vcprintf`

`[  4](sec  1)(fl 0x00)(ty   0)(scl   2) (nx 0) 0x00000000 __imp____conio_common_vcprintf_p`

Neither `printf` nor `_printf` appears in the list.  Does this mean it's not exported by that library?  If not, which library should I be linking?

According to [this MS article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/), `ucrt.lib` is the de-facto library for the c runtime and C standard library.

Comment: Regarding VS 2015+ and the lack of some of symbols being exported this other answer is likely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721059/call-c-standard-library-function-from-asm-in-visual-studio  . MS reworked the libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I tried manually linking `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` as well as the ucrt and it worked.  The legacy lib was in a completely different location though (my vs2017 install dir).  No sign of an equivalent in the windows sdk install dir.  Is there a better way to link this with everything I might need from the C standard library, or am I stuck specifying these sub-libs each time?

Comment: You'll need to include those compatibility libraries with the VS2015 toolset. The 2013 toolset however doesn't have refactored _C_ libraries so you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.  If you want to leave that as an official answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You may answer your own question here if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to a comment from Michael Petch, it looks like I need to manually link 1 or more extra libs which are in a completely separate location from the `ucrt.lib` library.  The relevant one for printf is `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib`, which I found deep in a sub-dir of my VS2017 install directory, as opposed to the `ucrt.lib` which is in the Windows SDK install directory.

The definition of `printf` is provided inline in `stdio.h` unless the macro `_NO_CRT_STDIO_INLINE` is defined, which I guess it usually is when building inside the VS toolchain.