# Hello World using NASM (and GoLink) on x64 64 bit Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, winapi, x86-64, nasm

I am currently learning assembly language for a custom compiler project. However, i wasn't able to make a single working assembly program.
I have an AMD CPU with a 64 bit operating system and a x64 based processor. I am using Windows 11.

I don't want to use c libraries as it kind of destroys the purpose of coding as low level as possible which is my objective.

I already tried a lot of different programs and linkers.

[Assembly Syscalls in 64-bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947915/assembly-syscalls-in-64-bit-windows)
This doesn't contain any working code.

[Hello world using nasm in windows assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574924/hello-world-using-nasm-in-windows-assembly/12575061#12575061)
I think this is for 32 bit systems, but i don't know what i need to change. I changed "eax" to "rax"
and this compiled and run but didn't print anything. I was also able to add random letters to thecode without any errors and still an exit code of 0. (Just one GoLink warning)

[Setting Exit Status in NASM for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70511327/setting-exit-status-in-nasm-for-windows)
Same problem here. I always get an exit code of one and the compiler doesn't care about any syntax errors.

I also tried using gcc and ld without success.

What am i doing wrong?

**Edit**
I tried this:
[How to write hello world in assembly under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembly-under-windows/27988874#27988874)
but link.exe seems to be only for visual studio (i am using vscode).
When i use GoLink, i get the following error:

```
Error!
The following symbol was not defined in the object file or files:-
MessageBoxA
Output file not made
```

**Edit 2**
When im using gcc, i get the following error:

```
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64- 
mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: 
out.obj:out.asm:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `MessageBoxA'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If i remove the message printing code, it works fine and i finally get an exit code of my choice! Is the MessageBoxA function in another library or something? How can i fix this?

**Edit 3**
I found this code and copied it, but again, it doesn't work. (editor's note: it's 32-bit code for the 32-bit calling convention.)

```
global _main
    extern  GetStdHandle
    extern  WriteFile
    extern  ExitProcess

    section .text
    _main:
        ; DWORD  bytes;    
        mov     ebp, esp
        sub     esp, 4

        ; hStdOut = GetstdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
        push    -11
        call    GetStdHandle
        mov     ebx, eax    

        ; WriteFile( hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
        push    0
        lea     eax, [ebp-4]
        push    rax
        push    (message_end - message)
        push    message ; ERROR
        push    rbx
        call    WriteFile

        ; ExitProcess(0)
        xor rcx, rcx
        call    ExitProcess

        ; never here
        hlt
    message: db      "Hello, World", 8
    message_end:
```

When i run this with the following command:

```
nasm -f win64 out.asm && gcc -o  out.exe out.obj -nostdlib -lkernel32
```

... i get a truncation error (idk what that means)

```
out.obj:out.asm:(.text+0x18): relocation truncated to fit: 
IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32 against `.text'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am a bit irritated why it's so hard to execut such a simple program.
I just need a hello world program for nasm, x64_64 windows with visual studio code and without c librarys.

Comment: [How to write hello world in assembly under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27988874) has a Windows x64 NASM answer that calls MessageBoxA.  You could call GetStdHandle / WriteFile instead to write to the console.  The link command it shows uses `link.exe`.  I don't know about Windows linkers.

Comment: Under Windows (unlike Linux), there's no documented stable ABI for making system calls directly, only via DLLs.  You say you want to avoid "C libraries", but unless you pick a specific kernel version and use its `syscall` numbers, you're going to have to at least use ntdll. ([System Calls in Windows & Native API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2489889)).  But Windows loads that into any process automatically so it's not an "extra" library, and it's not specific to C.  Hopefully you just want to avoid libc, not WinAPI. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions)

Comment: See also [FASM write Hello World to console with NO includes or dependencies at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63388863) re: how low-level is "low level" on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your ideas. @PeterCordes i tried your suggestion but i don't have link.exe. I updated my question with more info

Comment: `push    message ; ERROR` is trying to use a symbol address as a 32-bit immediate.  `lea` the address into a register and push that, like `gcc -fPIE` would do.  (Linux PIE has similar requirements to Windows LargeAddressAware executables, that any absolute addresses have to be 64-bit, but preferably you use only relative addressing so ASLR to anywhere in virtual address space (including outside the low 32 bits) doesn't even take any runtime fixups, especially not in read-only pages like .text.) [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)

Comment: Oh, also, that looks like 32-bit code.  Notice how it's pushing *all* the args, not passing the first 4 in RCX, RDX, R8, R9.  And it's using `lea     eax, [ebp-4]`, with 32-bit address-size.  It should work fine if you assemble it as `nasm -fwin32` and link it into a 32-bit executable.

Comment: I tried your suggestions by using registers according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170 and using lea instead of direct pushing. But this gives me the "relocation truncated to fit" error i already had. I also tried "lea eax, [message]" and then "mov r9, rax" but that didn't work. Should i add that information and the exact code as an edit?

Comment: You need to use `default rel`, or each memory reference has to be `[rel message]`, as mentioned in [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427); see also [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012).   I thought you were already using that in your 64-bit attempts, otherwise I'd have mentioned that in my comment.  (And I hadn't yet noticed that the code block in your edit was 32-bit code which had zero chance of actually working with `nasm -felf64`, even if you get it to link.)

Comment: Those are the right functions to call, but you need to reverse engineer back to what actual args are being passed, then write 64-bit code to pass those with the 64-bit calling convention to the same functions.  Also, you'll get the same link error as with the `MessageBoxA` version once you get it to assemble.  (I think `WriteFile` is defined in the same DLL as `MessageBoxA`, perhaps win32.dll?  I'm guessing here, you'd have to check what DLLs to pass as args to the linker.)

Comment: Could you make a working example as i'm a bit lost in all these dlls and formats and address sizes and so on. I don't think i'm able to produce working hello world code by myself and as you said, what i have is 32 bit code and i can't find any 64 bit windows example without printf.

Comment: You have the `MessageBoxA` example.  Oh, but `GetStdHandle` and `WriteFile` are defined in `kernel32.dll`, vs. `MessageBoxA` in `user32.dll`, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxa and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle.   Anyway, a google search for `site:stackoverflow.com windows x64 assembly getstdhandle` found Jester's answer on [How To Properly call 64 Bit Windows API In Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24902157) as the third hit for me.  I fixed one remaining bug with an edit.

Comment: The variable names for the global variables in that example are really clunky, there's nothing magic about `NtnNBytesToWrite`, it could just be `buf.len` or something.

Comment: Also related: [Input output in x64 assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44081355) shows MASM examples of calling `GetStdHandle` and `WriteConsoleW` / `ReadConsoleW` / `WriteConsoleW` to prompt and read input.  (Using UTF-16 wide chars).  As Cody points out, compiler output from an equivalent C function makes a good reference, e.g. https://godbolt.org/ and select MSVC from the dropdown, using `-O2`.

Comment: Wow it finally works! Thank you so much. I'm doing a compiler project right now and i guess it will need some time to implement that but it's still something to work with. I needed to add "default rel" but apart from that, jesters answer with your edit worked. Do you want to make an actual answer?

Comment: Also found ["Hello world" in x64 assembly for Windows - Shadow space / Stack alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73420722) - the code in the question works (and links to a github with build instructions).  That question is about why it still works when not aligning the stack properly.

Comment: I wouldn't know what to write for build instructions, so no I don't plan on writing an answer to this.  Like I said, I don't actually use Windows tools, I just know some about its calling conventions and some APIs.

Comment: Should i just leave it open or write what worked for me as an answer? That's my first question so i don't know what to do

Comment: Feel free to write up an answer yourself if you have the time.  That's encouraged on Stack Overflow to share what you've figured out with future readers.  The part that makes this not a duplicate is the details of the linker commands; Jester's answer from 2014 has working NASM source (although it's clunk and could be better.)  But the question and answer don't describe building + linking, so they're missing that part of what a tutorial would have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a bit of trying, I finally got it to work. Here is a cleaned-up version (by @PeterCordes) of the code that was in the first version of this answer. (Again, I am using Windows with an x64-based processor from AMD. I am coding in Visual Studio Code.)

```
default rel

extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile
extern ExitProcess

section .text
global main
main:
    sub     rsp, 40          ; reserve shadow space and align stack by 16

    mov     rcx, -11         
    call    GetStdHandle

    mov     rcx, rax         ; HANDLE is a 64-byte type on x64
    lea     rdx, [msg]       ; lpBuffer = RIP-relative LEA (default rel)
    mov     r8d, msg.len     ; DWORD nNumberOfBytesToWrite = 32-bit immediate constant length
    lea     r9, [rsp+48]     ; lpNumberOfBytesWritten pointing into main's shadow space
    mov     qword [rsp + 32], 0   ; lpOverlapped = NULL; This is a pointer, needs to be qword.
    call    WriteFile        ; WriteFile(handle, msg, len, &our_shadow_space, NULL)

;;; BOOL return value in EAX (BOOL is a 4-byte type, unlike bool).
;;; NumberOfBytesWritten in dword [rsp+48]

    xor     ecx, ecx
    call ExitProcess
  ; add     rsp, 40      ; alternative to calling a noreturn function like ExitProcess
  ; ret


section .data         ; or section .rdata to put it in a read-only page
    msg:  db "Hello, World!", 13, 10    ; including a CR LF newline is a good idea for a line of output text
    .len equ  $-msg    ; let the assembler calculate the string length
                       ; .len is a local label that appends to the most recent non-dot label, so this is msg.len
```

##### Assemble and link it with nasm and gcc:

```
nasm -f win64 out.asm   &&  gcc -o  out.exe out.obj -nostdlib -lkernel32
```

Omitted from this example: [stack-unwind metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=msvc-170&redirectedfrom=MSDN) for instructions that change RSP (`sub rsp,40`).  It will run fine without it as long as no SEH or C++ exceptions happen, but debugger backtracing up from inside `WriteFile` back through `main` to its caller won't work.  See *[Under what conditions do I need to set up SEH unwind info for an x86-64 assembly function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45333326/under-what-conditions-do-i-need-to-set-up-seh-unwind-info-for-an-x86-64-assembly)* for more.  If you're a beginner in asm and just want to understand how the "normal" stuff works, and aren't planning to actually use hand-written asm in production code, you don't need to worry about SEH and stack unwind info at all.

---

Commentary on the differences between this and the code in *[How To Properly call 64 Bit Windows API In Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902157/how-to-properly-call-64-bit-windows-api-in-assembly)* it was originally based on:

The only data we want in static storage (`.data` / `.bss` / `.rdata`) are the ASCII bytes of the string itself.  The output number of bytes can be pointing to stack space, and the constant we pass to WriteFile can just be an immediate in the machine code, not loaded from static storage (`dq 14`).  Also, it's generally good to [have the assembler calculate a length instead of hard-coding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly).

`WriteFile` needs somewhere to store the number of bytes actually written (since the return value is just a `BOOL`, unfortunately, unlike POSIX `ssize_t write()` which returns negative for error.)  We can use stack space (like a local variable) for this.  Since `main` is a function, it has its own shadow space.

(The example code copied from *[How To Properly call 64 Bit Windows API In Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24902157/how-to-properly-call-64-bit-windows-api-in-assembly)* used weird names like   `NtlpNBytesWritten` for a variable in BSS to point the `lpNumberOfBytesWritten` output arg of `WriteFile` at.  That's confusing since these aren't low-level NT functions, they're the Win32 API.  And the variable itself is just a dword so shouldn't have `lp` in its name if you are using static storage.)

The arg names in comments are from MS's documentation for `WriteFile`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefile

---

Other Hello World examples exist, such as an answer on [How to write hello world in assembly under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembly-under-windows/27988874#27988874) - that uses [`MessageBoxA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxa), which is in `user32.dll`, vs. [`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) and `WriteFile` being in `kernel32.dll`

Comment: I added a second section with a cleaned-up version of the code.  If I didn't introduce any bugs, you might want to remove the first version of the code that uses inefficient techniques like `mov     rdx, msg` (64-bit absolute addressing.)  Or not if you think my changes make it over-complicated for beginners.

Comment: Thank you @PeterCordes! One last question, what do the  2 numbers in this line mean? "msg:  db "Hello, World!", 13, 10"

Comment: That's Carriage Return (ASCII 13) and Line Feed (ASCII 10), which together form a Windows newline.  Like C `"\r\n"`.  In NASM you can also write them as `\r\n` but only inside backticks instead of single or double quotes.  https://nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.2

Comment: Okay, so i could add an infinite amount of characters like that?

Comment: Yeah, `db "foo"` is the same as `db 'f', 'o', 'o'`, and it takes an arbitrary list of byte values to assemble into the output.

Comment: Also related: [Shadow space example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33273797) shows a function that takes args, and passed them on to `WriteConsoleA` after calling `GetStdHandle`.