# Pass stack string as pointer to function

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64

I'm having an issue with trying to use a stack string as part of a win API function. My current code does the following

1. Create stack string
2. [Commented out] Call GetUserNameA with stack string as pointer
3. Call WriteFile to print output

When the commented out section remains commented out, the WriteFile function successfully prints out the stack string. However my commented out code is supposed to overwrite the stack string with my username but it hangs slightly instead due to an unknown issue.

```
extern GetStdHandle
extern WriteFile
extern ExitProcess
extern GetUserNameA

section .rodata

stdout_query equ -11

section .data

stdout dw 0
bytes_written dw 0

section .text

global start

start:
    mov rcx, stdout_query
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [rel stdout], rax

    sub rsp, 0x60; 48 bytes for the stack frame, and 48 bytes for the stack string
    mov rdx, rsp
    add rdx, 0x60
    mov dword [rdx], 0x414142; stack string
    add rsp, 0x30; allow the stack string to have 48 for stack space, 48 so it aligns with 16 

    ; i want to overwrite my stack string in rdx with my hostname from GetUserNameA
    ; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea
    ; GetUserNameA([out] LPSTR lpBuffer, [in, out] LPDWORD pcbBuffer) 
    ; sub rsp, 0x28 ; get stack space
    ; mov rcx, rdx ; move stack string location to rcx for function call
    ; mov rdx, 0xff ; max size of username 255
    ; push rdx
    ; mov rdx, rsp
    ; add rsp, 0x08 ; for alignment with push call
    ; call GetUserNameA
    ; add rsp, 0x28
    ; mov rdx, rcx ; move stack string back to rdx for WriteFile

    mov  rcx, [rel stdout]
    mov  r8, 0x3    
    mov  r9, bytes_written
    push qword 0
    call WriteFile

    xor rcx, rcx
    call ExitProcess
```

Requires linking to `kernel32.lib` and `advapi32.lib`

Comment: Are  you able to debug it?  Does it come back from `GetUserNameA`?  Does `rcx` survive as you are expecting it to?

Comment: @ErikEidt it seems to return fine, i haven't been using a debugger but i'll try it out. It appears to print an empty line, but it hangs which i guess usually happens when something isn't written correctly. `rcx` doesn't seem to survive as when i try to move it back to `rdx` and print, it gives no output

Comment: `rcx` is designated as call-clobbered for the windows x64 ABI, so we wouldn't expect it to survive.

Comment: Yes i think i've got it working thanks. I think it was a combination of stack alignment issues and `rcx` getting clobbered

Answer (score 0):

Solution below. Problem was likely being caused by `rcx` being clobbered and stack alignment issues.

```
    mov rcx, stdout_query
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [rel stdout], rax
    sub rsp, 0x08 ; i think this is needed for alignment not sure, seems to not work without it. Maybe it's the function call to get handle 
    
    sub rsp, 0x20 ; make stack space for byte array
    mov rdx, rsp
    add rdx, 0x20 ; make room far array
    sub rsp, 0x08 ; keep alignment with next push
    push rdx ; push rdx onto stack for later


    ; mov rcx, inventory
    mov rcx, rdx ; also add rdx stack array into variable 
    mov rax, 0x5
    push rax
    mov rdx, rsp ; push rax and then move to rdx for mem location
    sub rsp, 0x28
    call GetUserNameA
    add rsp, 0x28
    add rsp, 0x08

    pop rdx
    ; mov rdx, inventory
    mov  rcx, [rel stdout]
    mov  r8, 0x4    
    mov  r9, bytes_written
    push qword 0
    call WriteFile

    xor rcx, rcx
    call ExitProcess
```

Comment: You only reserved 2 bytes for `stdout` with `stdout dw 0`. You need to reserve 8 (with `dq 0`) since you need to store `rax` to it.  (`bytes_written` needs 4 bytes.)  Also, choose a different name, like `stdout_handle`. 
 `stdout` is the symbol name for a `FILE*` object in the C library; that's what most people will expect when they see code that accesses `stdout`.  I definitely thought "that looks wrong" and had to go see if you were defining your own symbol with that name or abusing the storage space at a symbol name defined by a library!

Comment: You're over-complicating the stack handling, and definitely calling `GetStdHandle` with a misaligned RSP.  It happens to work anyway; a lot of code doesn't use any 16-byte-alignment-required instructions on their own stack space, but it's still violating the ABI.  (And `start`'s return address is part of its shadow space when you do, which is ok if you're writing code that ends with `call ExitProcess`, but wouldn't work in a function that wanted to return.)

Comment: See also [Hello World using NASM (and GoLink) on x64 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77114093) for a `GetStdHandle` / `WriteFile` that handles the stack correctly.  (And correctly passes the 5th arg to `WriteFile`, unlike yours where `push 0` just affects the bottom of its shadow space.  Its 5th arg is at `[rsp+32]` before the `call`, so `mov qword [rsp+32], 0`.)

Comment: re: over-complications: adjust RSP once to reserve shadow space and outgoing stack arg space for your callees, and space for a buffer (and make it an odd multiple of 8 so you realign the stack).  Then do stuff like `lea rdx, [rsp+40]` to get a pointer to your buffer, above the shadow space and outgoing args.  (Or use your own shadow space above your return address) for the buffer if it's at most 32 bytes.

Comment: Also, you're using a buffer on the stack for a string, but you're using static storage for a 64-bit file handle?  Keep it in a call-preserved register like RBX or R12 or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm using stack buffer for a string but static storage for the file handle as I was using it just as an example to figure out how to create stack buffers. But will keep in the call-preserved register thanks

Comment: Interesting idea for the `mov qword [rsp+32], 0`, that makes things much nicer to handle

Comment: This is why it's a good idea to look at compiler output from existing known-good compilers, so see the "standard" way to do something in asm.  (Or *a* way, which is usually not terrible.)  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) - parts of it also apply to MSVC on https://godbolt.org/, or there's `gcc -mabi=ms` which should work on Godbolt, other than headers of course so you'd need to provide you own prototypes, if you want to see another compiler's output to see the similarities and differences.